# How to configure VSTS burn down chart to reflect story points

Tags: scrum, azure-devops, burndowncharts

Is there a way in Visual Studio Team Services (online) to set the burn down chart to reflect story points rather than task hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add the Analytics extension:https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-analytics
2. Edit your dashboard
3. Add the Burndown widget (not the Sprint Burndown widget)
   [image]
4. Configure the widget to show the Sum of Story Points: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-burndown-burnup-widgets?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 6):

<strike>We don't have that capability yet. There is a [User Voice suggestion](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2632616-allow-burndown-to-use-story-points-instead-of-hour) that is tracking your suggestion.</strike>

**Update:** this is implemented. [Configure a Burndown or Burnup widget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-burndown-burnup-widgets?view=vsts)

Comment: Does this widget still exist? When I try to add it to my dashboard, it doesn't appear in the list of available widgets.